# How do I make the viewer 'flip' the board?

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

Using the viewer... It's Black's move but I still want White on the bottom.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

Add the following line: `[StartFlipped "0"]`, just don't forget to indent it 4 times ( as same as you would when posting FEN ).

Comment: Indent it by four spaces, that is.