# Should the PGN viewer board show rank/file on the squares?

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I recently edited a [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32562/an-interesting-endgame) to convert the person's text description of where each piece was to an FEN diagram. Apparently this caused a little confusion as to which way the pawns were moving, as Black was on the move, which causes the replayer to show the board from Black's perspective.

I am aware that it is possible to [flip the board](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-do-i-make-the-viewer-flip-the-board) when making a diagram, but even so, when someone else views the board there is no visual indication of which way the board is oriented. The only way to tell, as far as I know, is to directly view the PGN. Obviously that's not an ideal solution.

Many boards (both virtual and physical) have a small 1-8 and a-h in the corners of some of the squares. Would it be possible to implement this in the replayer, to avoid confusion?

Comment: +1 I am having this exact problem with [If player A is in check but has a move which will checkmate player B without exiting check, is that move legal?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/39499/25131). Clearly, it is Black’s turn (since Black is in check), but that says nothing about which way the board is oriented.

Comment: In fact, the position is currently displayed as an image that includes rank and file labels. So I am tempted to just [leave it as it is](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/948/25131). But this is no good for those who [can’t access the image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img#attr-alt); I might post a follow-up question when I have time.

Comment: Done: [How should we serve users who cannot access images?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1056/25131)

Comment: I support this addition. It should be not too much complexity and will greatly aid beginners like me who don't know every square on the board by heart. And beginners make up most of the people asking questions, anyway.